# Can the information about tag editing limits be posted publicly?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Whenever a user reaches their daily vote limit, there's a handy popup that tells them **what the** (upvote) **limit is** and **when it will refresh**. However, when a user reaches a more unusual daily limit - **tag wiki edits** - they are not alerted. This information is also not found on any help page, so it's frustrating trying to figure out when editing will be available again.

[image]

When the limit has been reached, this red-orange box replaces the edit box. It describes tag wikis in a positive way but **does not mention a limit**. [An old meta question](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/551/can-we-please-standardize-the-phrasing-for-the-tag-wikis) is the only place that references any limit, but there its claims are unverified.

I'm requesting for this information to be put into a **help page** so that it can be easily accessed, as well as the **red-orange box** that appears when the limit has been reached, so that users understand how best to contribute to the community.

Comment: Sounds like a sensible idea to me. These limits are usually daily so most likely you will see the edit boxes back again now.

Comment: @TimB How or when can this information become public? It would really help me out.